# "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead" Error in Rselenium and Geckodriver-firefox

Tags: r, security, firefox, geckodriver, rselenium

I'm trying to access a page with RSelenium. I wrote my code in R and it is work fine in Chrome and IE. But when I'm using geckodriver, the firefox shows the below message and i recive an error in my R console:

[image]

```
Selenium message:
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info:os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I found that I should change the firefox profile but it is the python code and I need R:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
```

It should be like this in R

```
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = "D:/temp"))
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = fprof)
```

but i don't know what should I write exactly.

Would you please help me.
Or if you know how I could deactivate this warning!

Comment: I use Selenium C# and got around the problem with this Code:

 if (driverName == "firefox")
            {
                // Initialize the Firefox driver
                FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                
                options.AddAdditionalCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true, true);
                options.AddAdditionalCapability("acceptUntrustedCerts", true, true);
                //options.Profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true; <-- Does not work
               
                return new FirefoxDriver(options);
}

Answer (score 1):

Selenium requires that you set *both* the `acceptInsecureCerts` *and* `acceptUntrustedCerts` to `TRUE`. Besides, `remoteDriver` has been deprecated, so you now have to use `rsDriver`, as demonstrated here:

```
remDr=rsDriver(browser=browserName,extraCapabilities=list(acceptInsecureCerts=TRUE,acceptUntrustedCerts=TRUE))
```